# I don't think Naruto will post an answer without any vote

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash-2014

In celebrate the winter, we have a hat (actually, it's a headband) from Naruto:

> Accepted answer with no vote

Or in the detail box:

> Post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours

If I recall correctly, Naruto never said any neutral word. He will say a) wisdom words or b) dumb words (mostly b). I don't think Naruto will post an answer without any vote, even when some Hinata accepts it.

Comment: And, even more important *where is my straw hat???*

Comment: Are you referring to One Piece?

Comment: @Ooker He is!. And I also feel the Naruto Hat is wrongly named. Its more of Natsu (from Fairy Tail) where he is always saving the day but nobody cares.

Comment: Fun is integral part or Winterbash events, no need to add the tag. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Let me rewrite that message:

> You will be accepted/Become someone even if you had no friend before

Wasn't that the whole motivation behind the "I want to become Hokage"?
Seems appropriate to me.

Comment: It seemed obviously for me that in SE, we only have Hokage the first and the second. And the second one will be Hokage for the rest of his life.

Comment: The thing is, everyone hated Naruto initially. So by that logic. `Everyone will hate you, despise of you, look down on you. But in the end, they will accept you, and when they will, they will start looking up to you`